# Login/Register without Laravel's Authentication Services

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and felt that the Authorization system provided out of the box is difficult to customize and implement.

Is it a good idea to implement the Login/Register functionality from scratch using controllers and middlewares in laravel?

For example, a middleware 'webAuth' will keep a check on whether the user is logged in just by checking request->session()->has('userId').

The login controller will take email and password and search for user the user in database using email, get the password and Hash::check() it with the one provided by user during login. If the password check succeeds, the user will get be authenticated by setting $request->session()->put('userId', $user->userId).

Finally, a register controller can create a new user by taking in the details such as name, email, password, dob etc. using a form and creating a new user model. The user can then be logged in using the same method as mentioned above.

The login and register controllers will of course use Validator and may also redirect user appropriately.

Comment: This is pretty broad, what specifically do you find hard to customize about auth in Laravel?

Comment: The flow you are requesting here is exactly what the provided system will do, where do you have any limitations?

Comment: @Devon I need to integrate Social Login for one click user Authentication as we have seen on most web applications, i.e. without a password. Further, when I tried, I found myself messing up with all the files and directories of Laravel with no luck. I don't get the perfect view of how Auth is implmented which is an another shortcoming.

Comment: Is there any flaw in implementing it the way I mentioned?

Comment: @ParasJain, there are definitely easy ways to implement social logins into Laravel.  Check out packalyst.com and you'll find packages that already do this for you.  If you don't want to use one, you can at least check out the code to see how they do it.

Comment: @Devon I'm able to implement the Social Login functionality, and it works fine. I've separate controllers and routes for say facebook and google authorization. It's just one thing I want to clear - are there any downsides in such an implementation? Or should I just make up my self to use Laravel's auth?

Comment: For whatever it's worth it will be way easier for other developers if you use Laravel auth instead of some proprietary solution you cook up yourself. In addition Im sure the documentation is better, the code is better (more people who have contributed, more tests, more extensible), more plugins available, etc

Comment: Laravel has Socialite, which is for this purpose. There is a link in the Authentication documentation.